# Bulk remove '<i>' inside all '<blockquote>' using notepad++

Tags: wordpress, notepad++

I'm trying to bulk remove all  that appear inside the  from my WordPress Posts XML template. I have a huge file and since I'm changing of layout, all the  and  tags inside a quote should be removed, as the quote is already styled. How can I remove the tags without affecting the rest of my template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a search and replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) on your template file, using Regex mode :

[image]

Search for :

```
<blockquote>(.*?)<i>(.*?)</i>(.*?)</blockquote>
```

And replace by :

```
<blockquote>$1$2$3</blockquote>
```

**EDIT :**
This method will partially work for patterns like :

```
<blockquote>foo <i>bar</i> baz <i>qux</i></blockquote>
```

(ie. multiple `<i>` in a single `<blockquote>`). You just have to launch the search and replace several times, or use the recursive tag `(?R)` in your regex (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file in notepad++
2. Select all <blockquote> sections
3. Press Ctrl+H to open the Replace dialog box
4. Find <i>
5. Replace with nothing
6. Be sure to click the 'In selection' checkbox
7. Click Replace All
8. PROFIT!

[image: Notepad++ config]

Comment: This method looks great also but one question: how to select all <blockquote> sections in a file? I have something like 500 posts in my XML file

Comment: Use regular expressions, they're still very much a mystery to me; zessx's answer can tell you more than I can